# Scrollview like iAd gallery app

Tags: iphone, image, scrollview

i want to implement an iPhone scroll view like the iad scroller inside the app iAd Gallery of Apple.
Here is a link with an image example of what i mean : http://www.tipb.com/images/stories/2011/04/image-266x400.png

I want a little suggestion on which is the best way to start: i use UIImageView and affine transformation? It's too slow? Better if i implement this view with Quartz or other frameworks? 
Any suggestion or idea is really appreciated !

Thank's
Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a good place to start (and possibly a solution for your problem) would be to have a look at [iCarousel](https://github.com/demosthenese/iCarousel).

Comment: Thank's, this example is really nice ! It doesn't do exactly what i need, but it's a great starting point!